# why don't images with absolute url work in my css (laravel / vite)?

Tags: laravel, vite

I configured project with laravel 9 and everything works. Then I moved the layout and everything is fine too.

When I make a resource build, the site works correctly.

B0ut when vite runs server (0.0.0.0), then all the images that are registered in css do not work.

[image]

All images are in the public folder. And I move them over is not an option for me.

csss code:

```css
background-image: url('/img/home/sweets-one.png');
```

{my_local}/img/home/sweets-one.png - 200

http://0.0.0.0:3000/img/home/sweets-one.png - 404

vite config:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3000,
        open: false,
    },
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                // css
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Why you need add server options in config?

Comment: what vite version are you running ? Also server settings does not make any sense as long as you are running on a different web server

Comment: @Charlie, I use docker and I need to share port. but without server options it doesn't work too.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator, I wrote my local domain and port and everything worked. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Nepster Although it's not about the issue you asked, but there is no need to set server options, just run command `npm run dev --host` and set the docker forward port to correct, then you can easily view app with such as `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 1):

When running Vite using `npm run dev`, this will rewrite image URLs in your CSS files to be absolute URLs e.g. prefixed with `http://localhost`. `npm run build` will keep relative URLs like `/images/foo.jpg` unchanged so your app in production will be unaffected.

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
            transformOnServe: (code) => code.replaceAll('/images', 'http://localhost/images'),
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, If we user docker and local domain with custom port, you need configure Vite also.

For example:
My project use docker and works on the domain: mysite.loc:8080

So, Vite should be configured like this:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        host: 'mysite.loc',
        port: 8080,
        open: false,
    },
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                // css
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```